# SharePoint Admin Tool - Export list of all sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepointadmin

My SP Admin has used PowerShell for SharePoint online to export a list of SharePoint sites. However, this is simply a list of the urls and the site owners.

I really would like to get a more robust list that would include the hierarchy of sites, inheritance settings, and so on. Just put more than a simple listing.

Are there some tools that can do something like this?

Comment: Please read the help center. Asking for tools or offsite resources is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did not know that, but that is understandable. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can get site hierarchy details, broken inheritance and site users and group details using the following PowerShell scripts:

**Site and List:**

- http://www.sharepointfire.com/2016/01/get-site-web-and-list-information-with-powershell-for-sharepoint-online/
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint/retrieve-sharepoint-library-list-export-to-excel/24b33832-5e5c-401f-835a-0836d44f9088?auth=1
- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163602/export-sharepoint-online-list-to-csv-via-powershell

**Broken inheritance:**

- http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2014/07/sharepoint-powershellfind-all-broken.html

**User and groups:**

- https://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-use-powershell-for-sharepoint/#https://www.sherweb.com/blog/office-365-business-center/

Hope this helps.